# SQL Searching a data containing '%'

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-6

How do we search `Car%dinal` using LIKE operator?

I am actually doing a search functionality on customer name where I am sending query from entity framework. So when I send `car%` in search box, it shows both rows. Because that will form a query like `%searchstring%`.

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    
92          Cardinal    
93          Car%dinal
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify a LIKE escape character:

```
where CustomerName like '%car\%%' escape '\'
```

Or use `INSTR()` function:

```
where instr(CustomerName, 'car%') > 0
```

Comment: That worked, i am actually doing a search functionality on customer name where i am sending query from entity framework. So when i send car% in search box, it shows both rows.